# Why does Sheikh mention the thing about Train Pass after his wedding?

Tags: plot-explanation, lunchbox

In the 2013 Bollywood movie 'The Lunchbox', When Sheikh is escorting Fernandes to taxi after his wedding, he mentions an incident about Train pass.
He says that when he first traveled with Fernandes, he didn't have ticket,
but the next day he made himself a pass for the train.

After this scene there is a small pause and the Fernandes leaves.

What was the purpose of this scene ?
What did the director wanted to convey through this very dialog ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sheikh wanted to show fernandes that he is a big influence on his life and since he has taken him under his wing he has resolved to be a better man.